# React Bootstrap Modal failing on second use

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Building a react modal using the example [here](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/).  Shows set of radios, and handles selection.  Works fine the first time I select a list and hit save.  When I reopen the modal, `handleOptionChange` is not called when a new list is selected.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
class ListsDialog extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);
    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    this.handleOptionChange = this.handleOptionChange.bind(this);
    this.state = { showModal: false };
  }

  handleClose() {
    console.log("Changing list to " + this.state.selectedList);
    this.props.actions.changeList(this.state.selectedList);
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  handleShow() {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  handleOptionChange(changeEvent) {
    console.log("Selected option " + changeEvent.target.value);
    this.setState({
      selectedList: changeEvent.target.value
    })
  }

  renderList(list) {
    let radioId = "list-radio-" + list.id;
    let checked = list.id == this.props.listId ? "checked" : "";
    return(<div key={list.id} className="form-check">
             <input className="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exmampleRadio" id={radioId} value={list.id}
                    defaultChecked="{checked}" onChange={this.handleOptionChange}/>
             <label className="form-check-label" htmlFor={radioId}>{list.name}</label>
           </div>);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div id="lists-modal" className="modal fade" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div className="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
              <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
              <h4 className="modal-title">Switch List</h4>
            </div>
            <div className="modal-body list-list">
              {this.props.lists.map(list => this.renderList(list))}
            </div>
            <div className="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary save" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.handleClose}>Save changes</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>);
  }
}

export default ListsDialog;
```

Comment: Where are you referencing `this.state.showModal`? The code you posted doesn't seem to use it.

Comment: I believe that is used internally by react-bootstrap Modal.

Comment: How do you open the modal? Are you using references in parent component? I am afraid we can't do much without more example source code.

Comment: "I believe that is used internally by react-bootstrap Modal." That's a local state variable; react-bootstrap code has no access to it. Can you post more code showing how you open/close the modal?

Comment: I see that now, and also the defaultChecked attribute error, and am working to fix these issues

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it turned out my code wasn't based on that example, but I pure bootstrap one and as I recreated it, the dialog worked.